# Difference in usage between "en vouloir" and "tenir rigueur"

Tags: expressions, usage

> Je ne **t'en veux** pas **d**'avoir oublié mon anniversaire.
>
> Je ne **te tiens** pas **rigueur d**'avoir oublié mon anniversaire.

These two similar expressions seem to be essentially interchangeable on the surface, but I can’t help feeling that their usage is somewhat different.

In my limited experience of hearing native speakers use them, "en vouloir" seems to be often coupled with "de + infinitive", whereas "tenir rigueur" is followed more by "de + noun". So in the example sentence above, is the use of "tenir rigueur" off the mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*En vouloir* is personal and fits well with having forgotten a birthday.

*Tenir rigueur* is very formal and relates to strictness. You wouldn't use it in such a sentence. Or, eh well, possibly as a form of sarcasm, if you want to be perceived as very distant and cold for some awkward reason.

Grammatically both are fine.